# signalr ie9 back forward button troubles

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, internet-explorer-9, signalr

Using Asp.net mvc to develop an intranet portal. For some interactivity was used SignalR library. 
While navigating through site pages found strange issue. When sometimes i try to hit "back" or "forward" buttons in Internet Explorer 9 nothing is happened. When hitting "back" button and preious page loaded "forward" button after a moment become unavailable. 
When i place mouse cursor above these buttons it shows something like: "SignalR forever frame transport stream" or `http://server/signalr/connect?transport=foreverFrameconnectiontoken=....`
Is this by design and nothing to do with it or maybe some configurations can help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This issue appears to be a bug and @aleha has opened an issue on [GitHub](https://github.com/SignalR/SignalR/issues/2955).

For now at least a good workaround is to disable the foreverFrame transport:

```
$.connection.hub.start({ transport: ['webSockets', 'serverSentEvents', 'longPolling'] }, function () { ... })
```